# List out unmatched rows from the two dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, merge

**Raw1**

```
      Name     Age    Height
0    Ronaldo   25     189.0
1    Honey     26     193.0
2    Kola      14     200.0
3    Tree      19     155.0
4    Rot       22     165.0
5    Rat       28     170.0
6    Toy       30     172.0
7    Raft      32     156.0
8    Rifle     28     165.0
```

**Raw2**

```
     Name      Age     Height
0   Ronaldo    25      189.0
1   Honey      26      NaN
2   Kola       14      200.0
3   Tree       0       155.0
4   Rot        22      NaN
5   NaN        28      170.0
6   Toy        30      172.0
7   Raft       32      156.0
8   Rifle      28      165.0
```

I would like to list out the unmatched rows between these 2 dataframe. However, I can only list out the matched rows through merge by right_index.

```
raw4=pd.merge(raw1,raw2, on=['Name','Age','Height'], right_index=True)
```

**Current Output**

```
     Name  Age  Height
0  Ronaldo 25   189.0
2  Kola    14   200.0
6  Toy     30   172.0
7  Raft    32   156.0
8  Rifle   28   165.0
```

**Expected Output**

```
     Name    Age  Height
1   Honey    26   NaN
3   Tree     0    155.0
4   Rot      22   NaN
```

Comment: Why isn't row 5 of raw2 also listed?

Comment: Yeah, by right it should be listed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the DataFrames in an elementwise manner and then check for those rows where any of the items differ:

```
indexes = (raw1 != raw2).any(axis=1)
raw4 = raw2.loc[indexes]
```

Output:

```
    Name  Age  Height
1  Honey   26     NaN
3   Tree    0   155.0
4    Rot   22     NaN
5    NaN   28   170.0
```

Note that this approach won't work if both values from `raw1` and `raw2` are`NaN` (`NaN` is always different from any number, including `NaN`).

Comment: Just trying to understand the lines of code. The first one (indexes) stores the boolean values after checking the difference between raw1 and raw2 by columns. After that, " raw4 = raw2.loc[indexes] " prints the row of raw2 using the boolean values as the indicator indicating the differing rows? But I'm curious about the mechanism of raw2.loc[indexes]. Could you please explain how it is actually works? raw2.loc[boolean value]

Comment: `DataFrame.loc` can work in lots of differents ways. Here, it just creates a new `DataFrame`, containing the indexes where `indexes == True`. For more information see [pandas - Indexing and Selecting Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried modifying the value(inserting number) in the "Height" column in the latter dataframe and the code works. However, if I insert alphabets in the column, the code prints out every row instead.. What might be wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure actually. Maybe there's some implicit type conversion happening (?) In these cases I usually print out the result of each calculation and check where the code is getting wrong. And also make sure you check your dtypes (`df.info()` is pretty helpful).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I heeded your advice and checked the data type of each column. Indeed, the data type for the same column for the two tables were different. Once I converted every column to be string, everything works just like magic.